# How to send messages from Biztalk to MANY web services

Tags: soa, biztalk

Imagine we have a Notification service build on BizTalk. Once the service receives a notification it should then send this notification to other systems. If we have had 2-3 systems we could just add a few web service references and send the message thru corresponding port. But I wonder what if there are hundred of subscribed web services to which we should send a message? What's the best way to resend a message to 100 web services?

Comment: For hundreds of subscribers you'd normally supply a webservice they can poll. If you want to push from BizTalk you'd need to create 100 Send Ports subscribing to the message type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Filburt said! You would have one logical send port out of your orchestration and you would bind your orchestration to a send port group in the Admin console; so you could add or remove send ports at will. Any mapping could be performed outbound if any services need the message transformed too.

Comment: thank you! How to apply mapping for a service in send port group?

Comment: Hi javros, you could create a map to transform a message to a specific request for your service - this is assuming that you have some canonical message that needs to be transformed to different message types for your services. You would set each transform map in the Outbound Map property of each send port. That way, your orchestration sends a canonical message out and your send port transforms each message before it reaches your service.

Answer (score 2):

In agreement with Filburt + teepeeboy, and to add, if you offered push data services you would probably want control over each and every port, in order to control SLA's, Retries, possibly linked to billing, etc. You would likely need to increase the number of threads on the relevant WCF adapter and / or increase the number of Send Hosts and / or Clustered Servers for scalability.

You might also consider using an asynchronous adapter like MSMQ or MQSeries, as the chances that one of more of your 100 subscribers is down becomes higher. w.r.t. "ACK" replies, by restricting access on the queue and making the queue transactional, you could 'prove' that your subscriber had transactionally removed the message off the queue.